# How do I return multiple cards in loop in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, loops

I am new to react native. I have created A Card. In this card I get data from API. so if I get multiple Information. then I want that the cards should created Automatically . if 2 information comes from API then two cards should create and so on.

here is my code

```
   <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center",height:140, width:"90%", marginTop:30}}>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}>
          <Card center middle shadow style={{ height:80, width:"100%" }} >
          <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:190}}>
              
                    {this.props.route.params.mn[i]}
                    {'\n'} 
                    {this.props.route.params.ltn[i]}
                    </Text>
                    <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:190}}>
                    {this.props.route.params.mmn[i]}
                    </Text>
                    <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:150, flexDirection:'row'}}>
                    {this.props.route.params.mt[i]}
                    {this.props.route.params.ms[i]}
                    </Text>
                    <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:220}}>       
                    {this.props.route.params.mp[i]}
                    </Text>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like so:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

setData(DATA_FROM_API);
```

```js
<View>
 {
   data.map((element, key) => {
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}>
       // paste your card component
     </TouchableOpacity>
   })
 }
</View>
```

Comment: is this wright way to sending data in for loop =>   this.props.navigation.navigate  ("ListView", () => {
              for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) { 
     ltn1 = JSON.stringify(response[0].data[i].lead_tag_number).replace(/^["'](.+(?=["']$))["']$/, '$1')
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flatlist to show cards check the documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: is this wright way to sending data in for loop = >   this.props.navigation.navigate  ("ListView", () => {
              for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) { 
     ltn1 = JSON.stringify(response[0].data[i].lead_tag_number).replace(/^["'](.+(?=["']$))["']$/, '$1')
   }

Comment: don't send data in loop just send the  data you store in state